# item_databound is firing twice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Thank you in advance and please excuse if this one has previously been answered.

I wanted to display a record count. I put a counter in item_databound and noticed that the counter was double the records displayed.

I have a data access layer handling datagrids as:

```
Case "DataGrid"
            If Len(DataValueField) > 0 Then
                Dim oDS As New DataSet
                Dim oDV As New DataView
                oDV = DataTable.DefaultView
                oDV.Sort = DataValueField & " ASC"
                oDS.Tables.Add(oDV.ToTable)
                CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = oDS
                CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()
            Else
                CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = _DataSet
                CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()
            End If
            CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = _DataSet
            CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()
```

If I use this code on the page itself Item_Databound only runs once:

```
        Dim oDA As New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, _oConn)
        Dim oDS As New DataSet
        oDA.Fill(oDS)
        grdUsers.DataSource = oDS
        grdUsers.DataBind()
```

What am I doing wrong in my DAL that is causing the firing twice?

Thanks,
Fudd

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue clearly on your code.
In

```
    If Len(DataValueField) > 0 Then
```

you are binding your webcontrol for first time with oDS.And again after completion of If statement again you are binding you webcontrol with _DataSet.
What is logic behind this? What are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. When I run the code for the Dataset, with the the oDS,  I am not using the DAL code, the object code that I created.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not being more clear. When I use a dataset I get only one pass through DataBound. Using the object to get the data it passes through DataBound twice. What's wrong here? Thank you.

Here is the code on the page itself that calls the object code:

```
Dim Query As New FencelineDAL.Query(_oConn)
Query.CommandText = "[SELECT statement]"
Query.DataBind(grdUsers)
```

Here is the object that I think is causing the two passes:

```
Public Function DataBind() As Object
Select Case WebControl.GetType().Name
 Case "DataGrid"
      If Len(DataValueField) > 0 Then
          Dim oDS As New DataSet
          Dim oDV As New DataView
          oDV = DataTable.DefaultView
          oDV.Sort = DataValueField & " ASC"
          oDS.Tables.Add(oDV.ToTable)
          CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = oDS
          CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()
       Else
          CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = _DataSet
          CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()
      End If
End Select
      CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataSource = _DataSet
      CType(WebControl, DataGrid).DataBind()
  Return Webcontrol
```